# Button deleting all users in SQL Table

Tags: php, mysql, button, foreach

I have a website where I pull all the current active users from a program, and in the admin panel, I need to have a 'kill switch'.

It pulls the users from a SQL table 'online' and php make it an array.

```
<?php
    $stack = array();
    for($id = 1; $id <= 20; $id++)
    {
        $db = Database::getInstance();

        $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM online WHERE id = :id LIMIT 1');
        $stmt->execute([':id' => $id]);
        $user = $stmt->fetchObject('User');
        array_push($stack, $user);
    }
?>
```

This loops though the table and takes all the online users with the id [1;20].
It then stacks the $user in the array $stack.

```
<table>
    <thead><tr><th colspan="4"><span>Online right now</span></th></tr><tr><th colspan="4"> </th></tr><tr><th><span>E-Mail</span></th><th><span>Telefone</span></th><th><span>Unit ID</span></th></tr></thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php foreach ($stack as $num) : ?>
            <?php if($num != null) : ?>
                <tr>
                    <th><?=htmlspecialchars($num->email) ?></th>
                    <th><?=htmlspecialchars($num->telefone) ?></th>
                    <th><?=htmlspecialchars($num->unitid) ?></th>
                    <th><form action="thisPage.php" method="post"><input type="submit" name="killClick" value="Kill"/></form></th>
                </tr>
            <?php endif ?>
        <?php endforeach ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This simply goes though the $stack assigning each $user or $num to a row in the table, the row contains the users email, telefone number, unitID and the a button.

```
<?php
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST" and isset($_POST['killClick']))
    {
        $passedId = $num->id;

        try
        {
            $db = Database::getInstance();

            $stmt = $db->prepare('DELETE FROM online WHERE id = :id LIMIT 1');
            $stmt->execute([':id' => $passedId]);
        }
        catch (PDOException $exception)
        {
            error_log($exception->getMessage());
            return false;
        }
    }
?>
```

The above PHP is located on the same page, and outside the foreach loop.

So currently when I press the button, it deletes all the users in the table 'online'... why? And how do I make it only delete the user I'm clicking on?

Comment: The form within the loop is not passing any ID value to the delete function ~ perhaps you ought to have a hidden field in there with the ID for that particular entry so that it gets passed when the form is posted

Comment: Oh yeah didn't think of that! Will try that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To send the ID for each particular record include a hidden field in the form that is generated in the loop and then use `$_POST['id']` for the `$passedID` value in the delete portion of the script.

```
<?php
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=="POST" and isset( $_POST['killClick'],$_POST['id'] ) ) {

        $passedId = $_POST['id'];

        try {
            $db = Database::getInstance();

            $stmt = $db->prepare('DELETE FROM online WHERE id = :id LIMIT 1');
            $stmt->execute( [ ':id' => $passedId ] );
        } catch( PDOException $exception ) {
            error_log( $exception->getMessage() );
            return false;
        }
    }
?>




<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th colspan='4'><span>Online right now</span></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th colspan='4'></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th><span>E-Mail</span></th>
            <th><span>Telefone</span></th>
            <th><span>Unit ID</span></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php foreach ($stack as $num) : ?>
            <?php if($num != null) : ?>
                <tr>
                    <th><?=htmlspecialchars($num->email) ?></th>
                    <th><?=htmlspecialchars($num->telefone) ?></th>
                    <th><?=htmlspecialchars($num->unitid) ?></th>
                    <th>
                        <form action='thisPage.php' method='post'>
                            <input type='hidden' name='id' value='<?=$num->id;?>' />
                            <input type='submit' name='killClick' value='Kill'/>
                        </form>
                    </th>
                </tr>
            <?php endif ?>
        <?php endforeach ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

You could possibly simplify the first sql query using the `between` operator rather than using a loop.

viz:

```
$num=array();
$db = Database::getInstance();

$sql='select * from `online` where `id` between :id_low and :id_high;';
$stmt=$db->prepare( $sql );

if( $stmt ){
    $stmt->execute( array( ':id_low'=>1, ':id_high'=>20 ) );
    $num=$stmt->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_OBJ );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the $_POST['num'] when submitting the form.

By the way you can use GET for this case id ?>">killClick